# How do I refactor this signup form without using SASS?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple signup form using this `HTML`. Am I separating my code properly here or is there some code that I could remove/change?

The form looks good visually, but when I styled it with `CSS` I noticed a lot of stuff I had to repeat.

```html
<body>
    <form action="#" class="form">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <h1>Join our community of developers from all over the world</h1>
      <div class="form-box">
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="password">
          <label for="password">password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="password2">
          <label for="password2">confirm password</label>
          <input
            id="password2"
            type="password"
            placeholder="confirm password"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up" />
      <p>Already have an account</p>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Here is my CSS.
**Is there a better way to style each form `input` and `label` without having to separately use `display: flex` each input like I did below?**

```css
.form {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1391ff, #0145ff);
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 120px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #0000008f;
}

.img-overlay::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/06/13/18/mosaic-2721424_960_720.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -20%); */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.18;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.589);
}

.form h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#email,
#email::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.password {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#password,
#password::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.password2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

#password2,
#password2::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0145ff;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.473);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

I feel like I'm repeating a lot of code in the CSS, but I'm not sure if I am doing it properly even though my code creates the sign up form and everything looks good aesthetically.

Comment: Is this all of your CSS?

Comment: Yeah it's a small project

Comment: To be honest with you, there isn't a lot of code repetition here. About the only thing that repeats is the width and height for .form and .image-overlay. While many fields are repeating, their values are different. You might want to look into inheritance but their won't be much code reduction.

Answer (score 1):

There were few places where you could have optimized your CSS:

1) As all `inputs` were having the same style. Instead of declaring style for each `input` separately, you could have declared the global style on `input` only.

2) As all `labels` were having the same style. You can just make a common class (I made `form-container` ) and put it on all rows and put the style in that.

3) `Button` hover - only add that CSS which are getting change. Rest will be inherited from the parent `button` property

Below is the optimized code.

```css
.form {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1391ff, #0145ff);
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 120px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #0000008f;
}

.img-overlay::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/06/13/18/mosaic-2721424_960_720.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -20%); */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.18;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.589);
}

.form h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

input,
input::placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231, 0.8);
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0145ff;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.473);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="#" class="form">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
      <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <h1>Join our community of developers from all over the world</h1>
      <div class="form-box">
        <div class="form-container">
          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-container">
          <label for="password">password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-container">
          <label for="password2">confirm password</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="confirm password"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up" />
      <p>Already have an account</p>
    </form>
  </body>
```